# Theme Check gives: Required: This theme doesn't seem to display tags?

Tags: theme-development, tags, testing

I am testing my theme with *Theme Check plugin* and it shows this message:

> Required: This theme doesn't seem to display tags?

Picture:

[image]

How can i fix this?

Comment: Please add the error message as text (like you did in the title) as this is more compatible with text search for future users. Just keep it in mind for your future questions, I edited yours now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to be using one of these functions to display a list of tags associated with the post:

- `the_tags()`
- `get_the_tag_list()`
- `get_the_term_list()`

Otherwise the check will fail.

If you're building this theme for use with a project that doesn't need tags, don't bother adding support. If you're intending on uploading it to WordPress.org for review, then you need to add support for tags.

Comment: where can this be added.

Comment: @TheWPNovice wherever you want the tags to display

Comment: I dont know where, but theme check is giving this warning. so I have to get rid of theme check warning. But my question is where should I Use this? In the style.css?

Or somewhere in the functions.php so that it can take value from here →

Tags: one-column, two-columns, right-sidebar, flexible-header, accessibility-ready, custom-colors, custom-header, custom-menu, custom-logo, editor-style, featured-images, footer-widgets, post-formats, rtl-language-support, sticky-post, theme-options, threaded-comments, translation-ready This theme, like WordPress, is licensed under the GPL.

Comment: You'll want to use it inside the loop, in content.php (if you have it), or otherwise single.php, archive.php, index.php, blog.ph.p, etc. This function is not for the theme tags, it's for displaying the tags that are attached to posts

Comment: How can we populate all the tags list if we are one a tag page like this → `www.somedomain/tag/apple/` I have posted the question [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/281935/entire-tag-list-not-getting-fetched)